# Regex for numbers with spaces and + sign in front

Tags: javascript, regex

If i want to accept only numbers then i will use this regex

```
^[0-9]*$
```

but the problem here is that the numbers like

`+1 00`

are not catched and my regex will show that it is invalid

The user needs to type only numbers but only one space in between is allowed and + sign at the beggining should be optional.

So acceptable is:

```
+1 11 1 1 11 
or
1 11 1 1 11
```

Unacceptable is:

```
+1    11 1 1 11
or
1 11     1 1 11
```

please help

Comment: `^\+?\d+(?: \d+)?$`

Comment: regex101.com is a good place to test out regexs :)

Comment: Are those spaces at the end of your numbers supposed to be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using this regex pattern:

```regex
^\+?\d+(?:[ ]?\d+)*$
```

Sample script:

```js
console.log(/^\+?\d+(?:[ ]?\d+)*$/.test('+1 11 1 1 11')); // true

console.log(/^\+?\d+(?:[ ]?\d+)*$/.test('1 11 1 1 11'));  // true

console.log(/^\+?\d+(?:[ ]?\d+)*$/.test('+1    11 1 1 11')); // false

console.log(/^\+?\d+(?:[ ]?\d+)*$/.test('1 11    1 1 11'));  // false
```

The regex pattern used here says to:

```
^                 from the start of the string
    \+?           match an optional leading +
    \d+           then match one or more digits
    (?:[ ]?\d+)*  followed by an optional single space and more digits,
                  zero or more times
$                 end of the string
```

Comment: Why the `?:` ? It works without it https://regex101.com/r/4ZaZYs/1

Comment: @NinoFiliu The `?:` just turns off the capture group, since we don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Close!

```
/^[0-9]{1,}$/g


^ = start/first character
[0-9] = Select only number 0-9 but match it once,
{1,} = Match it one or more times,
$ = look no further, so cut all spaces, letters or non matches out!
```

or even

```
/^[0-9]+$/g
```

or even (preferred)

```
/^-?[1-9]\d*\.?(\d+)?$/g
```

You should not match anything more but numerals.

```js
function CheckInt(inputNum) {
  if (inputNum.toString().match(/^-?[1-9]\d*\.?(\d+)?$/g)) {
    console.log(`${inputNum} is a number (INT)`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${inputNum} is not a number (INT)`);
  }
}
CheckInt("a");
CheckInt("b");
CheckInt("c");

CheckInt("102 020");
CheckInt("102-1029");

CheckInt(5400);
CheckInt(-2);
CheckInt(20);
CheckInt(2042992540);
```

Comment: Does not match `+1 1` eventhough it should